# Does anybody know the LEGO number for this white ship with 6 wings?

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

Does anyone know the LEGO set number for this?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is not a LEGO set, it is a clone brand. The indentations on the slopes show this. You will also find that the studs do not bear the LEGO logo.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

- Company: *Cra-Z-Art*.
- Clone Brand: *Super Blox*.
- Set Name: *Space Fighters*.
- Year: *2010*.